# Why does to_datetime produce only missing values for a float column in pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, types

I am confused by something in pandas 0.18.0. In my input csv data, a field is supposed to consist dates as YYYYMMDD strings, but some rows have this missing or misformatted. I want to represent this column as datetime with dates where possible, and missing where not.

I tried several options, and what got me furthest was not using `parse_dates` upon reading the table in (with `read_table`), but then coercing the conversion with `pandas.to_datetime(DataFrame['Seriesname'],  errors='coerce',format='%Y%m%d')`. This is robust to typos where the number cannot represent a date (think '20100231', column imported as `int64` first) or when the string does not represent a number at all (think '2o1oo228', column an `object` upon import).

What this procedure is not robust to is when the columns contains only numbers but one field is empty. Then `read_table` imports the entire column as a `float64` (not an `int64`, which has no missing values in numpy), and the conversion above produces all missing, even for rows where the data makes sense.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: What do you mean by "no conversion"?  Can't you just set the conversion options to leave that column as a string?

Comment: @BrenBarn See the edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way might be to avoid `float`s altogether. Preempt the conversion to numerics in `read_table` by specifying `dtype`, with the column in question being kept an `object`. `to_datetime` handles that as intended.

HT: BrenBarn in the comments.